# Prove $\forall a,b$ where $a < b$, $\exists x\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a<x<b$ and $x$ has a finite decimal expansion with some number of 7's in it.

Tags: calculus, cardinals

> $\forall a,b$ with $a < b$, $\exists x\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a<x<b$ and $x$ has a finite decimal expansion with some number of $7$'s in it.

I have shown that there are infinite number of rational numbers in between an interval of two arbitrary real numbers but I don't understand how to proceed afterwords.

Comment: Since $a$ is different than $b$, there must be some point in the decimal expansion where they first disagree.  Try changing one of the decimals that follows that point to a seven.  For example, if $a=1.335\color{red}{5}8 < 1.335\color{red}{8}8=b$ then you might choose $x=1.3357$.  Some care needs to be taken as to which digit you change and how you address infinitely repeating $9$'s, etc...

Comment: Are you requiring that you can do this for $\textit {any}$ specified number of $7's$?  If so, I don't think it is true.  Any rational between $.777777$ and $.7777771$ has at least six $7's$ in its expansion.

Comment: @lulu Oh sorry I thought it would be true for any specified number of 7's.  But no, I just need to show that there is a 7 in the decimal expansion of $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find such rational number $x$, we  modify suitably the classical proof of the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $b>a$ then there is an positive integer $n$ such that $10^n(b-a)>10$. It follows that the interval $(10^na,10^nb)$, whose size is greater than $10$, contains an integer $m$ with $7$ as unit digit. Hence $x:=\frac{m}{10^n}\in (a,b)$ and $x$ is a rational number which contains at least a $7$ digit in its decimal expansion.

P.S. By taking a larger $n$ such that $10^n(b-a)>10^d$, we can find a rational number $x$ with at least $d$ digits $7$.

Comment: Dear downvoter, if you think that my proof is wrong, then I'd like to read your comments.